# What will break on IPv6 day?

Tags: ipv6

As you are probably aware [World IPv6 day](http://isoc.org/wp/worldipv6day/) is coming on 8 June. Our network is IPv6 enabled, so the basics are all there, but our users currently defaults to IPv4 for almost everything (IPv6 is <1% of the external traffic). I have verified that our DNS servers handles IPv6 properly, but I am not certain what to expect when the users start to get AAAA records for services like Google and Akamai.

- What should I expect to break on World IPv6 day?

Comment: [test-ipv6.com](http://test-ipv6.com/) is a site that runs some diagnostics on your browser's IPv6 readiness. You may find it interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is nothing or very, very little. The link you posted says that those organizations will offer their content over IPv6, it does not say that they won't continue to offer their content over IPv4.

Probaly 99.9% of the worldwide network structure is not ready to move exclusvely to IPv6. Do you believe that those content providers would purposefully cut off 99.9% of their user base for a full 24 hours... as a test?

Comment: To add to that, you can see what's going to happen on IPv6 day for you by hitting the v6-enabled versions of some of the big sites, such as http://ipv6.google.com; all that's going to happen on IPv6 day is that the AAAA records will be published on the main name.  The only people that should really have issues are those with broken v6 tunneling setups.

Comment: I am well aware of dual stacking and that the content will be available over IPv4 as well. I am also aware of that we still have students using pirated versions of Chinese windows 98 on our network, and we have had routers that crashed on IPv6 traffic. Changes tend to be painful, but I will be pleasantly surprised if this doesn't break something.

Comment: @pehrs - Win98 doesn't even have any IPv6 support at all built-in. So, they wouldn't be affected at all, right?

Comment: @pehrs: I think I've got a better take on your question. Your question is not "Oh noes, the interwebz are down!". Your question is "What might we expect to see happen with currently deployed IPv6 implementations?" Am I on track?

Comment: Yes, that summarizes much better what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

As Joe said. If you read their [FAQ](http://isoc.org/wp/worldipv6day/faq/) on their site, they answer this:

> How will World IPv6 Day impact
>   Internet users?
>
> One of the goals of World IPv6 Day is
>   to expose potential issues under
>   controlled conditions and address them
>   as soon as possible. The vast majority
>   of users should be able to access
>   services as usual, but in rare cases,
>   misconfigured or misbehaving network
>   equipment, particularly in home
>   networks, may impair access to
>   participating websites during the
>   trial. Current estimates are that
>   0.05% of users may experience such problems, but participating
>   organizations will be working together
>   with operating system manufacturers,
>   home router vendors and ISPs to
>   minimize the number of users affected.
>   Participants will also be working
>   together to provide tools to detect
>   problems and offer suggested fixes in
>   advance of the trial."